# Infinite series of matrices almost but not quite matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

I'm working on a problem that has brought up for me the need to address infinite series of the following form,
$$
\sum_{i=k}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}A^{i-k+1}
$$
where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. If $k = 0$, then this is clearly the power series of a matrix exponential. If $A$ were a real number, $x$, then it's easy to see that
$$
\sum_{i=k}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-k+1} = \frac{1}{x^{k-1}}\left(e^x-\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{i!}x^i \right),
$$
by simply equating to the power series of the exponential function (at least I think I got those indices right).

I assume that the same thing would hold if $A$ were invertible; unfortunately, in my case $A$ is not invertible. However I have verified that my sums do converge to something, so I figured I'd ask if anyone had any idea of a way to simplify my infinite series.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? The right hand side of your scalar equation defines an entire function on the complex plane, which is no worse than $e^z$ in any respect except it lacks the multiplication identity...

Comment: Exactly---I want something like the right hand side of my scalar equation, but for the matrix equation. Basically I want to reduce my matrix equation to something that isn't an infinite sum.

Comment: Erm... But even $e^z$ is an infinite sum! $e^A$ is just a fancy name for it and it is neither better, nor worse than $F(A)$ where $F$ is the function defined by your equation...

Comment: Okay, for context I am trying to approximate exp(Q) where I can decompose Q = A+B, and I can easily analytically compute exp(A) and exp(B). I want to make an approximation in which I am basically neglecting terms that are higher order than linear in B, and after doing a bunch of manipulations I end up with a bunch of terms that look like the series in question multiplied by B times some constant. So I'm hoping that if I can simplify these series, I will be able to come up with a slick approximation to exp(Q).